# nginx net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: nginx, netty

I am trying to hit a URL on nginx which be proxied to Netty, for a particular URL I am getting net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on chrome and on Safari some times it works and some times not.

```
Here is the configuration: 
location /service-order-api {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host:$server_port;
    proxy_pass http://service_order_api;
    #proxy_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    #proxy_buffers 8 24k;
    proxy_redirect off;
    #proxy_buffering off;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
  }
```

Comment: I solved it by setting proxy_set_header Connection ""; and using keep alive connection to Netty.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this option for your server:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Don't know the reason, but this solved my case.